# Elixir "Package not found in registry: :hackney" problem

Tags: dependencies, elixir, version, elixir-mix

I am attempting to add coverage to my project, but
keep running into problems.

I've attempted all the suggestions in the error
message at the bottom of this listing.

I have a large project that I wish to add coverage
for unittest, but all the coverage packages bomb
similarly.

I started a clean project, "bug", with *only* the mix deps()
addition so interference gets minimized.

Any help would be appreciated.

Versions:

```
rebar3 --version
rebar 3.13.2 on Erlang/OTP 22 Erts 10.4.3

elixir --version
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
Elixir 1.9.4 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)

erl --version
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.4.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]
Eshell V10.4.3  (abort with ^G)
```

The mix.exs in deps

```
defp deps() do
  [
    #{:coverex, "~> 1.5", only: [:test], runtime: false},
    {:excoveralls, "~> 0.13.0", only: [:test], runtime: false},
    {:idna, "~> 6.0.1"},
  ]
end
```

I've used different versions of coverex and excoveralls but the
results are the same.

I notice:

```
"Bad dependency version for httpoison (and others...)"
```

but I don't understand what to do about this either.

The error/warning messages appear to be related to the dependencies.
Shouldn't dependencies resolve these themselves?

Here is the listing:

```
=> mix clean
=> mix deps.get
Resolving Hex dependencies...
Dependency resolution completed:
Unchanged:
  certifi 2.5.2
  excoveralls 0.13.0
  hackney 1.16.0
  idna 6.0.1         # Below it says idna 6.0.1 not found - why?
  jason 1.2.1
  metrics 1.0.1
  mimerl 1.2.0
  parse_trans 3.3.0
  ssl_verify_fun 1.1.6
  unicode_util_compat 0.5.0
All dependencies are up to date
Command completed
=> mix test  # Try to run default test on a new repo
===> Package idna-6.0.1 not found. Fetching registry updates and trying again...
===> Updating package registry...
===> Writing registry to /home/cecilm/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry
===> Generating package index...
===> [appsignal:1.6.2], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.6-beta.1], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.0], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.7.0-alpha.4], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.0-beta.1], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.3], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.7.0-alpha.3], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [batch_loader:0.1.0-beta.4], Bad dependency version for absinthe: ~> 1.4.0 or ~> 1.5.0-beta.
===> [prometheus_httpd:2.1.10], Bad dependency version for prometheus: ~> 3.5 or ~> 4.2.
===> [batch_loader:0.1.0-beta.5], Bad dependency version for absinthe: ~> 1.4.0 or ~> 1.5.0-beta.
===> [appsignal:1.7.0-alpha.2], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.7.0-alpha.1], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [batch_loader:0.1.0-beta.6], Bad dependency version for absinthe: ~> 1.4.0 or ~> 1.5.0-beta.
===> [appsignal:1.12.0], Bad dependency version for decorator: ~> 1.2.3 or ~> 1.3.
===> [appsignal:1.6.1], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.5], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.6-beta.2], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.6], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.7], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [appsignal:1.6.4], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> [batch_loader:0.1.0-beta.3], Bad dependency version for absinthe: ~> 1.4.0 or ~> 1.5.0-beta.
===> [appsignal:1.6.0-alpha.1], Bad dependency version for httpoison: ~> 0.11 or ~> 1.0.
===> Writing index to /home/cecilm/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/packages.idx
===> Package not found in registry: {<<"idna">>,<<"6.0.1">>}.
(Mix) Could not compile dependency :hackney, "/home/cecilm/.mix/rebar3 bare
compile --paths="/home/cecilm/play/Elixir/bug/_build/test/lib/*/ebin"" command
failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile hackney",
update it with "mix deps.update hackney" or clean it with "mix deps.clean
hackney"
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on _Elixir_ 1.10 but search against SO returns many issues with `idna`. Try to upgrade _Elixir_ to the latest in the first place.

Answer (score 20):

This is a compatibility problem with Erlang's `rebar` package manager and the `idna` dependency. You need to update rebar in your project by running

```
mix local.rebar
```

at the command line. This should fix the problem.

Comment: @TrailingDots **here on SO you are obliged to mark the correct answer with a green checkbox.** People do help you, please find some time to help future visitors.

Answer (score 7):

(from my [crosspost on elixirforum.com](https://elixirforum.com/t/package-not-found-in-registry-hackney-problem/32052))

Removing the local rebar3 and mix installations, as well as the currently fetched dependencies and their compiled versions solves this issue.

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/rebar3 ~/.mix deps _build 
mix deps.get
```

hex will tell you if new versions are available as far as I remember, the version of rebar installed and used via mix local.rebar is determined by the version of mix (so elixir) you use. It is constrained by an *exact* version match, not a (semantic) range.

Therefore the good habit is to run mix local.hex when hex tells you it can be updated after a mix deps.get, while you should run mix local.rebar after each update of elixir.

Do this once a week. Some kind of tricky bug relating to dependencies…

Comment: It is usual to accept the answer even when you answered it yourself, so you make it clear to people who find it later that it solved your problem.